# JSON values are showing NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

While retrieving JSON array data using $.each method, I am able to get the array values, but apart from that it's showing 'NaN' values and showing the below error.

*"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '5' in Hello!"*

Seems it's looping through all the objects not only array, if this is the case how can I get only array values and how can I get all the values(including and excluding array values).

one more query does this **rawgit** works for only method '*GET*', because while using method '*POST*' throwing error(403 (Forbidden)).

```
    $.ajax({ 
                method: 'GET', 
                url: 'https://rawgit.com/rajeshdesigner/testgit/master/colorsdata.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) { 
                    $.each(data, function(index, obj){
                        $.each(obj, function(index, element) {
                            $('#show-data').append(element.key + element.value + '<br/>');
                        });             
                    });
                }
           });
```

JSON:

```
{
      "items": [
        {
          "key": "First",
          "value": 100
        },{
          "key": "Second",
          "value": 200
        },{
          "key": "Last",
          "value": "Mixed"
        }
      ],
      "obj": {
        "number": 1.2345e-6,
        "enabled": true
      },
      "message": "Hello!"
    }
```

Comment: if your variable 'data' is json, you can do $.each(data.items, function() {})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you only want to iterate `data.items` but you're iterating over everything. Try this:

```
$.each(data.items, function(index, obj) {
  $('#show-data').append(obj.key + obj.value + '<br/>');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rrsku4Lq/

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, got same kind of solutions from others as well, but need to vote for only one so accepted your's.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when the second loop reaches `"message": "Hello!"`, that is not a object to be looped again, so for that element only the first loop is needed.

To correct, just make an if statement to enter the second loop only in case `obj` is an Object.
I also changed the nested loop `index` name to `index2`.

```
$.each(data, function(index, obj){
    // Only do nested loop if obj is Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        $.each(obj, function(index2, element) {
            $('#show-data').append(element.key + element.value + '<br/>');
        });             
    }
});
```

If you're only interested in data.items, than you can use

```
$.each(data.items, function(index2, element) {
    $('#show-data').append(element.key + element.value + '<br/>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your solution and explanation as well.

Comment: While using the first solution still getting NaN, if it is not object it should not show NaN.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unnecessary for loop. The response is one JSON object in your case. You simply need to iterate the data items. UPDATE: How you handle a response depends on what you want to accomplish. In practice, you'll generally know how to access the data you need from the response, but as others have suggested, you can iterate through the keys in the response object and check for types

```js
var object = {
  arr : [1,2,3],
  nestedObject : { }
};

for (var key in object) {
  console.log(key);
  console.log('Is array? ' + Array.isArray(object[key]));
  // Now you can handle the data based on it's type...
}
```

In this case, you could choose to expect the response to include a `items` key and iterate over that. (It's also good practice to validate that you can process the response)

```js
 $.ajax({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'https://rawgit.com/rajeshdesigner/testgit/master/colorsdata.json',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
     // data is your JSON object.
     data.items.forEach(function(item) {
       $('#show-data').append(item.key + item.value + '<br/>');
     });
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-data"></div>
```

Also, 403 indicates that the resource is blocked for the current user. Verify that your POST method is publicly accessible and that you are authorized to make the request.

Comment: Exactly. He was looping over the object and its subobject (which aren't all arrays or objects). He wants to loop just for the `items` array inside the `obj` object.

Comment: @Max Sindwani : Thanks and appreciate your solution and also you have clarified regards errors and rawgit POST.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the json first. And as @Jason P said, iterate `data.items`

```
$.ajax({ 
        method: 'GET', 
        url: 'https://rawgit.com/rajeshdesigner/testgit/master/colorsdata.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
            var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(parsedData.items, function(index, obj){
                $.each(obj, function(index, element) {
                    $('#show-data').append(element.key + element.value + '<br/>');
                });             
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through all the elements in the array. I think you need to loop through only 'items' element as only that element contains the 'key' and 'value' elements.

Even though you are doing that, you can check if the key and value element exists, and if it does, do whatever your code wants.

```
           $.ajax({ 
                method: 'GET', 
                url: 'https://rawgit.com/rajeshdesigner/testgit/master/colorsdata.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) 
                { 
                    $.each(data, function(index, obj)
                    {
                        $.each(obj, function(index, element) 
                        {
                            if(element.hasProperty('key') && element.hasProperty('value'))
                                 $('#show-data').append(element.key + element.value + '<br/>');
                        });             
                    });
                }
           });
```

Comment: you had given one more approach, gr8 and thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax({ 
                method: 'GET', 
                url: 'https://rawgit.com/rajeshdesigner/testgit/master/colorsdata.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) { 
                    console.log(data.items);
                    $.each(data.items, function(index, element) {
                            $('#show-data').append(element.key + element.value + '<br/>');
                        });
                }
           });`

Comment: Appreciate your solution.